# How to make a video as a splashscreen with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, splash-screen

I am using AngularJS and Material Design framework. I want to play video in splashscreen.
I don't know how to do this. I searched but couldn't find anything! Please tell me how I can write this or send to me a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Take a look at http://www.videogular.com/tutorials/how-to-start/ it solved my Problem.

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp',
  [
   "ngSanitize",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster"
  ]
 )
 .controller('HomeCtrl',
  ["$sce", function ($sce) {
   this.config = {
    sources: [
     {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"},
     {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.webm"), type: "video/webm"},
     {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.ogg"), type: "video/ogg"}
    ],
    tracks: [
     {
      src: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/subs/pale-blue-dot.vtt",
      kind: "subtitles",
      srclang: "en",
      label: "English",
      default: ""
     }
    ],
    theme: "bower_components/videogular-themes-default/videogular.css",
    plugins: {
     poster: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/images/videogular.png"
    }
   };
  }]
 );
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl as controller">
  <videogular vg-theme="controller.config.theme">
   <vg-media vg-src="controller.config.sources"
     vg-tracks="controller.config.tracks">
   </vg-media>
  </videogular>
 </div>
</div>
```